# spring boot html redirect

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I am using AngularJS along with Spring boot.

In my **RestController**, I am passing in a JSON object. My end goal is to invoke the new html.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="loadPatientDetails", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String loadPatientDetails(Model model, @RequestBody Info patientInfo){
        System.out.println("Inside loadPatientDetails "+patientInfo.getId());
        model.addAttribute("json", new Gson().toJson(patientInfo));

    return "html2";
}
```

My AngularJS calling code is the following:

```
function (patientId){
    return $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : '/loadPatientDetails',
        data : patientId,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
    }).then( function(status){
        return status;
    });;
};
```

**Problem**: I am getting back a complete html i.e. html2 in the response.. what I need is that html2 should automatically be rendered.

What am I missing?

Comment: your service call return response as html string and do you want to render that html to you DOM(current html). is that right ? \

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Its working for many different pages i.e. the way I have defined the controller it usually will automatically map to the html via the name of the return String.  But somehow for this very code bit its not working.

Comment: show more controller code

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="registerPatient",    method=RequestMethod.POST)
                public String addPatient(Model model, @ModelAttribute Info patientInfo){
   model.addAttribute("retrievedPatientInfo", patientInfo);

   return "html1";
  
  }